# Typescript - Use base interface as generic type

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, polymorphism

In an Angular application, I am using a base interface with some common properties and two child interfaces extending it:

```
interface BaseConfig {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   type: ConfigType 
}

interface UserConfig extends BaseConfig  {
   socialNr: number;
}

interface OrderConfig extends BaseConfig  {
   shipDate: Date;
}

enum ConfigType {
   User: 'user',
   Order: 'order'
}
```

The goal is to leverage polymorphism and use the base class as type for both child interfaces, for example:

```
export interface State extends EntityState<BaseConfig> {
  loaded: boolean;
  selectedBookConfig: BaseConfig | null;  // This can be either UserConfig or OrderConfig
}
```

On the component side I can check the type and cast accordingly:

```
 if (this.config?.type == ConfigType.User) {
     this.view = (this.config as UserConfig).socialNr;
 }
```

The problem is however in the templates, where I get errors for the child properties, missing in the base interface. In the following snippet, I would refer to the case of an UserConfig:

```
// config has the base type: `BaseConfig`

<div [ngSwitch]="config.type">
    <span [ngSwitch]="ConfigType.User"> {{ config.socialNr }} </span>
</div>
```

The error is: `Property 'socialNr' does not exist on type 'BaseConfig'.`

How could I use a base interface as root/generic type for its extending interfaces/types without incurring in the template issues as above?

Comment: `UserConfig` and `OrderConfig` doesn't extends`BaseConfig`, is that normal ?

Comment: They do, I forgot it in the snippet, thanks

Comment: Ok, no problem :). And are you sure it's `UserConfig` the type of the object ? else, with a cast like `myObj as UserConfig` ?

Comment: The cast works on the component side, but it does not in the template,

Comment: I think you can do a getter in component that return needed type, and check if it find socialNr

Comment: Yes, that would work, even though the solution is not very performant when I have several properties (the case above is an extremely simplified version of my DTOs). I will keep the question still open for now in case of other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways.

1. Convert into object

Such as explained in comments, if you have few types you can do like that:

In your template :

```js
{{ getUserConfig.socialNr }}
```

In your component :

```js
public get getUserConfig(): UserConfig {
   return config as UserConfig;
}
```

2. Get value from obj

If you have lot of type (such as in your case), you can use this:

```js
{{ config['socialNr'] }}
```

Both works fine (in my case, tested with angular)

Answer (score 2):

You should have `State` be a generic type as well, e.g.:

```js
export interface State<T extends BaseConfig> extends EntityState<T> {
  loaded: boolean;
  selectedBookConfig: T | null;  // This can be either UserConfig or OrderConfig
}
```